# asp.net chart control vertical labels

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, charts

I am using following to draw charts on my asp.net razor web application. However, due to long product names on the x axis, labels don't align properly. Is there any way to rotate the labels and display them vertically?

```
 var myChart2 = new Chart(width: 1200, height: 400, theme: ChartTheme.Blue)
.AddTitle("Most Popular Products")
.SetXAxis(title: "Product")
.SetYAxis(title: "Item Price")
.AddLegend("Legend")

.DataBindTable(ViewBag.numberOfOrders, xField: "product")

.Write();
```

Comment: I answered this same question [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41740709/razor-chart-helper-how-to-change-axisx-text-orientation/41741214#41741214).

Comment: Awesome that did the trick. I added +1 to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much ! +1 right back at you...:O)

Comment: Note that the **theme** normally goes into an XML file, which makes it much easier to read and maintain. In that case the user preferred to have it in a string.